# I would like to generate via javascript a url to the current page and to add two parameters

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, smarty

I'm using the sharethis plugin in a smarty template. And in the twitter is shared link which looks so :

```
<span class='st_twitter_large' st_via="mediajobscom" st_url="MY URL HERE" displayText='Tweet'>
```

I would like to generate via javascript a url to the current page and add two parameters to the url like `?featuredid=id?featuredname=name`:

```
http://domain.com/currentpageisurl?featuredid=id?featuredname=name
```

I don't have much knowledge with javascript please try to make things clear to me, especially what i need to insert to `st_url="THE CODE HERE"`.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: You only need one `?` to indicate the start of the query string.  All other parameters should typically be separated by `&` (I say typically as this is the de facto standard parameter separator but others can sometimes be used depending on server/application configuration)

Comment: My problem is that i don't know how to use javascript to make it share the current page is url with two parameters.

Comment: This is very easily Googled...

Comment: In the sharethis plugin i can add a smarty code variable like $link so that the <span class='st_twitter_large' st_via="mediajobscom" st_url="{$link}" displayText='Tweet'> But i don't know in smarty code template is language how to add a parameter to this variable.

Comment: Even when i found the answer i couldn't find how to do it exactly.

Comment: So you are saying this solution doesn't need to be made in javascript, but could also be made in PHP?  It seems, in that case, you would just need to modify `$link` directly to append your parameters to it - a simple string concatenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can find the value for the URL of the current page in:

```
document.URL
```

You would want to assign this to a variable:

```
var myURL = document.URL;
```

and then add the parameters... the comment from Mike Bryant is absolutely correct...  a parameter in a url should be like this:

```
http://myURL.com?parameter1=whatever&parameter2=somethingElse
```

as long as you are using very basic parameters (no spaces, strange characters [like quotes, amperstands, etc.]) and you know them in advance when you write the page, you can simply tack them onto the string with the + sign:

```
var myURL = document.URL+"parameter1=whatever&parameter2=somethingElse";
```

But this greatly depends on what those parameters might be, what values they are going to have, and how you are going to determine that.

It might be that these parameters get defined only when the user interacts with the page, and they might be different every time and contain really strange characters; so this simple solution might not work well for you.

Feel free to update the question if your situation is too complicated for this solution.

Comment: Well, my url looks like so : [link](http://domain.com/search-results-jobs/?keywords[all_words]=accountant&Location[location][value]=&Location[location][radius]=10&start=0&search_type=title)[/link]  I would like to try your script but should i just past it into my href ? or should i create it between <script> tags and call for it in my href ?

Comment: Thank you a lot @steve you really saved my day, i entered my script like so  <script>var myURL = document.URL+"parameter1=whatever&parameter2=somethingElse";</script>  and to call it i added an onclick,  onclick="window.location.href=myURL;" . Thanks a looooot!! And

Comment: You can do it either way... if you already have the href, you can just inject it there just as easily... if you need a better solution, just ask.  If this one worked, though, please don't forget to mark it as answered.

Comment: Sorry i didn't know how to set it as answered, i wish i had enough reputation to vote for your answer! Thanks again Steve!!

Comment: No problem.  Anytime.